# Adding heights of two elements jQuery

Tags: jquery

Ok, so what im trying to achieve is an accordion type sidebar navigation but it does not slide, the panels are only open if you are on the respective page.

My problem:
In jQuery, i would like to give the container the height of the container PLUS the height of the div below each respective "Active" accordion item which is positioned absolute. (.accordion-inner).

Please have a look at my syntax and if I am writing the correct jQuery to achieve this.

My jQuery:

```
    var Container= $('.SopsNav');
    var InnerAccordionHeight = $('.accordion-inner')'
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#sidebar').css({ height: SidebarHeight.height() + InnerAccordionHeight.height() });
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem I find in your code is the extra quote in 2nd line

```
 var Container= $('.SopsNav');
    var InnerAccordionHeight = $('.accordion-inner')'  //<--remove the extra quote here
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#sidebar').css({ height: SidebarHeight.height() + InnerAccordionHeight.height() });
    });
```

Change it to  `var InnerAccordionHeight = $('.accordion-inner')`

Comment: LOL! Cant believe I missed that! Working perfectly now thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I see syntax error

```
   var Container= $('.SopsNav');
   var InnerAccordionHeight = $('.accordion-inner');
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#sidebar').css({ height: SidebarHeight.height() + InnerAccordionHeight.height()    });
   });
```

Use ; instead ' in second string.Try this.